# #pragma warning(disable:4251) not working for 3rd party sdk

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pragma

My project compiles without warnings in VS2013 but updating it to VS2017 generates several [C4251](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4251?view=vs-2017) warnings that say a class needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients. The warnings are coming from the headers of a 3rd party DLL. (The DLL uses STL classes in its interface.) I added the usual pragmas around the include headers to quiet the warnings:

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable:4251)
// 3rd party headers here
#pragma warning(pop)
```

But that didn't quiet a single warning. Is there an alternate approach?

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: If the warning refers to a template then the warning also needs to be disabled in any code that causes the template to be instantiated.  Comment out the pop to see if that makes a difference.  Do beware that this is a pretty gross diagnostic.

Comment: @HansPassant. Thanks for the thoughts. Removing pop didn't help but led to some testing and turns out my original code block works as long as I'm not including headers that include more headers from the problematic SDK? Not sure why that would be, but some overdue code cleanup should fix the problem.

Comment: You are not sharing nearly enough info.  My crystal ball says that this started to go downhill when looking for a linker error when you first tried this.  Caused by a static library that was not rebuilt in VS2017.  There is no workaround for that, you really do have to get it rebuilt.

Comment: Sorry @HansPassant, I thought it was obvious. Yes, the library was not built in VS2017 (most current build is VS2015). I get these errors during compile (no linking attempted), so nothing to do with a linker error. Regardless, I'm working with the SDK distributor to get a VS2017 build.